# How can I add more tags for other's questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I have seen my own question edited by site users and they altered some tags. I do not know how to do that. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Crazy: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2627487/revisions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have 500 points to be able to retag posts. (See the FAQ for more info.)

Answer (score 3):

**500** points needed for that ability.